# First person character controller controllable by GUI buttons

Tags: user-interface, controller, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I've been unlucky in searching for a solution on the furums which I am not able to find. I need to figure out how to make it possible for a classic First person character to be controlled by GUI butons (arrows) instead of the cassual WASD style

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the arrow keys on the keyboard, it works by default with the Unity FPS controller in the 'Character Controller' package.

If you are not already using this package, you can import it by selecting Assets -> Import package -> Character Controller.

If you mean GUI buttons as in on screen controls, I would strong recommend that you don't. Because to click on any of these buttons, you have to move the mouse to that position, and then you can't control which direction the FPS controller is moving.